# Rails 3: Using a POST form on the index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

In my Rails 3.0 app I have a series of very large search forms on my resource:index page, requiring the use of POST instead of GET.

Currently, the app is routing the POST request to resource#create, when I want it to route to resource#index. I realize this is the RESTful route, but need to override it. How can I do that, while also preserving the ability to create a new record of that resource?

Thanks much.

Comment: Doesn't using POST for a search form kind of contradict the REST paradigm? Wouldn't a GET be more appropriate?

Comment: The GET is definitely more appropriate, but the url length limit is too small for all the search params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off having a "search" action that is post-only - and then renders the index template eg:

```
class MyController < ...
  def search
     @my_things = MyThing.find_with_search_params(params[:search]) 
     render :action => :index
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use index, just add this in Rails 3 routes:

```
resources :my_things do
  post :index
end
```

Comment: isnt the created url conflicting with the create method?

Answer (score 0):

So you want your "create" action end-point in the controller to do 2 things - Respond to search and do the create also? Bad idea, but the solution might be as simple as using an "if" condition in the create action to do one or the other. If its not a satisfactory answer, feel free to clarify your question a bit more.

Comment: I see how that's a bad idea, and would like to avoid it. I guess I was hoping that there was a routing solution rather than using the create controller for both. Perhaps just moving the url for the searching off the index page to something like resource/search or resource/all.

Comment: If you were really restful, this would work seamlessly. /resources URL with a GET would hit index action and do a search and /resources with a POST would hit the create action and well, do a create. Your view has to ensure that the search link/button is the GET method and create is using a POST. This IS the routing solution. /resources with GET => index and /resources with POST => create.